# (Java) BufferedReader of a socket only takes one line at a time, requires client input before receiving the next line

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, bufferedreader

I have a server and a client.

My issue is that my client can only receive one line from the `BufferedReader in` at a time. To receive the next line, the client must respond. How can I make the client receive all of the input at once? For instance, a multi-line input.

```
try (
        Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);                   //Connect to server
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);  //The socket output stream sends an output to the server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));                //The socket input stream receives an output from the server
    ) {
        BufferedReader stdIn =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));           //The BufferedReader allows the client's input to be iterated through
        String fromServer,
               fromUser;

        while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {                      //while there is an input from the server
            System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);                    //Print the input

            fromUser = stdIn.readLine();                                    //Receive a line of user input
            if (fromUser != null) {
                System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                out.println(fromUser);                                      //Send it out to the server
            }
        }
    } catch [...]
```

Comment: Perhaps use separate threads? Have you considered trying this?

Comment: Why do you care? What difference will it make?

Comment: @EJP I need the full multi-line message to appear

Comment: 'Message' being defined how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different threads - one to send messages and another to recieve messages.

Client side code:

```
class Client5 extends Thread{

static Socket s;
static int end=0;

public void run(){
    String str1;
    //read data coing from server
    try{
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        while(end==0)//recieve from server
        {
            str1=br.readLine();
            System.out.println("from server:"+str1);
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    s=new Socket("192.168.43.231",1111);
    //send data to server
    DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());


    //read from keyboard
    BufferedReader kb=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String str;

    Client5 read=new Client5();
    read.start();   
    //reapea till exit is typed by client
    while(!(str=kb.readLine()).equals("exit")){

        dos.writeBytes(str+"\n");//send to server   
    }
    dos.writeBytes(str+"\n");
    end=1;
    s.close();
    dos.close();
    kb.close();
}
```

}